# No response from the Get-InstalledModule

Tags: powershell

I have the PowerShell 7.2.1. installed on windows 10 Enterprise.

I am not getiing any response from the powershell command "Get-InstalledModule".

The cursor just moved to the next line and keep blinking.

Comment: Well, that would indicate you haven't installed any modules... what's your question?

Comment: Do you mean that you know have modules installed, and they are not being returned by `Get-InstalledModule`? If so what is the value of `$env:PSModulePath`? Or do you mean the command hangs indefinitely?

Comment: later I have realized that I have Windows PowerShell 5 installed as well. Once I disabled it from the Group Policy, I get response faster with the powershell prompt.